The behavior of $f\left(x\right)=\left\{f\left(x-1\right)<10^p:f\left(x-1\right)^2,\log \left(f\left(x-1\right)\right)\right\}$
I was experimenting with an equation on my calculator, which can only handle numbers smaller than $10^{100}$, and I developed the following algorithm:
I choose a number n, then I square it. If the result is equal or greater than $10^{50}$, I take the log of it; otherwise, I just square it again, and so on.
I noticed that for any number I chose, the lowest value would converge to something around 56. I wrote the equation in Desmos to test if this was actually true, and I used the following equation:
$$f\left(0\right)=c$$
$$f\left(x\right)=\left\{f\left(x-1\right)<10^{p}:f\left(x-1\right)^{2},\log\left(f\left(x-1\right)\right)\right\}$$
And I tested it for values of p and c, and observed that the local minimum of $\lim _{x\to \infty \:}f\left(x\right)$ would only depend on p and would not be affected by c (as long as −1>c or c>1, of course).
I also noticed that, for some values of p, the lower points of the graph would alternate between certain values.
c = -3.4 and p = 30
c=-7.2 and p = 65
May someone explain to me why this equation behaves this way and why the lower points seem to converge to some random value?
